# Create homogenous matrices by filling with NaN R

Tags: r, matrix

I have several matrices that are all different sizes with slightly different orders. I am trying to organize the matrices so I can average them. The most straightforward way (I thought) would be to create equal matrices, then use one of the solutions previously suggested, e.g.
`Reduce("+", my.list) / length(my.list)`

I was thinking that it might be possible to create a template matrix that is 10x10 then apply each matrix to the template, so that if the matrix being applied isn't 10x10 (e.g. it's 4x4) the rest of the matrix would be filled with NaNs. I've provided three example matrices and three matrices that look like I hope the output would look.

Three sample matrices:

```
           0         1  2         3    4 5 6         7   8 9
0  0.7134503 0.0000000  0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0 0
1  0.6800000 0.0000000  0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0 0
2  0.2352941 0.2941176  0 0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0.4117647 0.0 0
3  0.3333333 0.0000000  0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.2 0
4  0.0000000 0.0000000  0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0 0
5  0.5000000 0.0000000  0 0.0000000 0.25 0 0 0.0000000 0.0 0
6  0.6000000 0.4000000  0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0 0
7  0.5250000 0.0000000  0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0 0
8  0.6060606 0.0000000  0 0.2121212 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0 0
9  0         0          0 0         0    0 0 0         0   0

          0   1         2         3         4 5 7   8 9
0 0.5550000 0.0 0.0000000 0.2200000 0.0000000 0 0 0.0 0
1 0.6363636 0.0 0.2727273 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0 0.0 0
2 0.4516129 0.0 0.0000000 0.2580645 0.0000000 0 0 0.0 0
3 0.4150943 0.0 0.0000000 0.3679245 0.0000000 0 0 0.0 0
4 0.7647059 0.0 0.0000000 0.2352941 0.0000000 0 0 0.0 0
5 0.4285714 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 0 0.0 0
7 0.2000000 0.2 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.0000000 0 0 0.2 0
8 0.3000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.7000000 0.0000000 0 0 0.0 0
9 0.5555556 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.2222222 0 0 0.0 0

          0 2         3 4 7 8
0 0.4020101 0 0.5075377 0 0 0
2 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0 0 0
3 0.6322581 0 0.2322581 0 0 0
4 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0 0 0
7 0.0000000 0 0.0000000 0 0 0
8 0.4883721 0 0.3488372 0 0 0
```

Desired output:

```
           0         1 2  3         4    5 6 7         8   9
0  0.7134503 0.0000000  0 0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0
1  0.6800000 0.0000000  0 0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0
2  0.2352941 0.2941176  0 0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.4117647 0.0
3  0.3333333 0.0000000  0 0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.2
4  0.0000000 0.0000000  0 0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0
5  0.5000000 0.0000000  0 0 0.0000000 0.25 0 0 0.0000000 0.0
6  0.6000000 0.4000000  0 0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0
7  0.5250000 0.0000000  0 0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0
8  0.6060606 0.0000000  0 0 0.2121212 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0
9  0.7272727 0.0000000  0 0 0.0000000 0.00 0 0 0.0000000 0.0

          0   1         2         3         4 5 6 7   8 9
0 0.5550000 0.0 0.0000000 0.2200000 0.0000000 0 NA 0.0 0
1 0.6363636 0.0 0.2727273 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 NA 0.0 0
2 0.4516129 0.0 0.0000000 0.2580645 0.0000000 0 NA 0.0 0
3 0.4150943 0.0 0.0000000 0.3679245 0.0000000 0 NA 0.0 0
4 0.7647059 0.0 0.0000000 0.2352941 0.0000000 0 NA 0.0 0
5 0.4285714 0.0 0.0000000 0.0000000 0.0000000 0 NA 0.0 0
6 NA        NA  NA        NA        NA        NANA NA  NA
7 0.2000000 0.2 0.2000000 0.2000000 0.0000000 0 NA 0.2 0
8 0.3000000 0.0 0.0000000 0.7000000 0.0000000 0 NA 0.0 0
9 0         0   0         0         0         0 NA 0   0

          0 1  2         3 4 5 6 7 8 9
0 0.4020101 NA 0 0.5075377 0 NANA0 0 NA
1    NA     NA NA     NA   NANANANANANA  
2 0.0000000 NA 0 0.0000000 0 0 0NANANA
3 0.6322581 NA 0 0.2322581 0 0 0NANANA
4 0.0000000 NA 0 0.0000000 0 0 0NANANA
5     NA    NANA      NA   NANA NA NA NA
6     NA    NANA      NA   NANA NA NA NA
7 0.0000000 NA 0 0.0000000 0 0 0NANANA
8 0.4883721 NA 0 0.3488372 0 0 0NANANA
9     NA    NANA      NA   NANA NA NA NA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick approach: get the set of unique column and rownames across the list. Create a new matrix with these dimensions, and then use subset mechanism (by row and col names) to assign values.

```
# some dummy data
m1 <- matrix(1:4, 2, dimnames=list(0:1, c(0,3)))
m2 <- matrix(1:9, 3, dimnames=list(0:2, 0:2))
lst <- list(m1, m2)
#> lst
#[[1]]
#  0 3
#0 1 3
#1 2 4

#[[2]]
#  0 1 2
#0 1 4 7
#1 2 5 8
#2 3 6 9

# Get unique col and row names
nc <- sort(unique(unlist(lapply(lst, colnames))))
nr <- sort(unique(unlist(lapply(lst, rownames))))

# loop through matrices
lst2 <- lapply(lst , function(x) {
  out = matrix(NA, ncol=length(nc), nrow=length(nr), dimnames=list(nr, nc))
  idx = as.matrix(expand.grid(rownames(x), colnames(x)))
  out[idx] <- x
  out
  })
# lst2
#[[1]]
#   0  1  2  3
#0  1 NA NA  3
#1  2 NA NA  4
#2 NA NA NA NA

#[[2]]
#  0 1 2  3
#0 1 4 7 NA
#1 2 5 8 NA
#2 3 6 9 NA
```

One comment on your use of `Reduce("+", my.list) / length(my.list)` is that the sum wont work as (I think) you expect if there are `NA`. But could get them by

```
s <- simplify2array(lst2)
rowMeans(s, dim=2, na.rm = TRUE)
#  0 1 2   3
#0 1 4 7   3
#1 2 5 8   4
#2 3 6 9 NaN
```

---

Another approach to get the means

```
d <- Reduce(function(...) merge(..., by=c("Var1", "Var2"), all=TRUE), lapply(lst, reshape2::melt))
v <- rowMeans(d[-(1:2)], na.rm = TRUE)
xtabs(v ~ Var1 + Var2, data=d)
#    Var2
#Var1 0 1 2 3
#   0 1 4 7 3
#   1 2 5 8 4
#   2 3 6 9 0
```